# Vim delete lines using regex and adding them to registry

Tags: vim, neovim

I have these mappings:

```
vnoremap <leader>dab "hy:v/<c-r>h/d<cr>
vnoremap <leader>daa "hy:g/<c-r>h/d<cr>
```

Which removes multiple lines by regex search, however, the lines are just deleted, and I'd like them to go on a registry so I can pase them following running these commands.

Can this be achieved by this regex search and delete?

EDIT:
I can see that they are added to different registers, Can I make the ex-command be saved to a single register?

Comment: A simple approach, which has several drawbacks: `vnoremap <leader>daa "hyqeq:g/<c-r>h/d E<cr>` which stores the deleted lines into `@e`

Comment: Cool that works! can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining my solution `vnoremap <leader>daa "hyqeq:g/<c-r>h/d E<cr>`:

- `"hy` stores the visual selection into `@h`
- `qeq` is equivalent to removing the content of `@e`
- `d E` after `g//` is the command `:d` but it uses the **uppercase** register `@E`, which means it will append new content into it, instead of overwriting

However, this has some drawbacks:

- Using `<c-r>h` into the mapping can break the command, e.g. if the selection contains slash characters; you can avoid a few unpleasant cases by adding `\V` in the pattern, but it's far from perfect: `vnoremap <leader>daa "hyqeq:g/\V<c-r>h/d E<cr>`
- An extra empty line is prepended into the `@e` register

Comment: Much obliged. Few words about the `\V`?

Comment: See `:help /magic`. It makes the pattern "nomagic".